# How to set a default password for wildcard host in tramp?

Tags: tramp, ssh

I have a list of hosts 192.*.*.* with a default user and password, I've tried to set wild-card in `.authinfo.gpg` but it still requests password when I try to login.

There are no problems when it set per host IP.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `auth-source` package does not support host wildcards. Tramp is using this package for password handling.

Comment: So, can I populate `.authinfo.gpg` with range or network? 192.168.1.1/24 as an example?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a feature, see the auth-source manual `(info "(auth)")`. Maybe you write a wishlist request via the Emacs Bug Tracker.

Comment: What about just using ssh keys and adding the key to the hosts you want to login with. With modern key rings and ssh agent, you won't need to enter passwords apart from the initial ssh-agent one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in TRAMP, as has already been pointed out, but you can partly do this in your SSH config. (I merely assume that you are using SSH, because what other options are there? Hopefully you are not using telnet.)

You should read the `ssh_config` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for the details, but you can put something like this in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host 192.168.0.?
User hellseher
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/filename
```

You cannot set a password this way, but you can specify which key pair to use using the IdentityFile declaration. This lets you log in without a password.

Answer (score 0):

At pointed out by @michael-albinus, `auth-source` does not support explicit host wildcards. It does however support fallback matching, so a `.authinfo.gpg` containing

```
machine foo login bar password pass-bar

login baz password pass-baz
```

will return "bar/pass-bar" for host "foo" and "baz/pass-baz" for every other host.